# Customize the Dictionary and List output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a List and Dictionary as below:

```
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
```

I need to display output in below format:

```
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 ruby
1 dagger

Total number of items: 48
```

I have tried to make a sum of similar dictionary keys. However couldn't write the proper logic.

I'm unable to find the correct logic as i'm new to the programming world.

Below is the expected output I need to display:

```
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 ruby
1 dagger
Total number of items: 48
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen the other 2 solutions but as you're new to programming i think its best to keep it simple, lets try to avoid using any libraries.

First we want to loot the dragon (meaning combine the dragonLoot array and add it to our inventory):

```
for item in dragonLoot:
    if item in inv:
        inv[item] += 1
    else:
        inv[item] = 1
```

our inventory now looks like:
`{'gold coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'ruby': 1}`

Now after we've looted the dragon we just need to display our loot, we're just gonna iterate over the dictionary while printing each value.

```
sum = 0
for item in inv:
    print("%d %s" % (inv[item], item))
    sum += inv[item]
print('Total umber of items: %d' % (sum))
```

Now we can keep the adventure going!

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

total = Counter(inv) + Counter(dragonLoot)
for k,v in total.items():
    print(v, k)
print('Total number of items: %s' % sum(total.values()))
```

Output:

```
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 ruby
1 dagger
Total number of items: 48
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use counted -

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(inv) + Counter(dragonLoot)
s = sum(d.values())
for k, v in d.items():
    print (k, v)
print ("Total number of items: ", s)
```